# Error with all rails commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, fedora

I used to develop with rails on Linux mint, for some reasons i turn to fedora.

I install all the packages and gems using rbenv correctly, But i can't work on my project

Ex: every time i use `rails server` the terminal output is:

```
/home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE - /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `require'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:78:in `each'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:78:in `block in require'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:67:in `each'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:67:in `require'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /home/bassemustafa/rails/depot5/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `require'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `block in perform'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `tap'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `perform'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bassemustafa/rails/depot5/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/bassemustafa/rails/depot5/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/bassemustafa/rails/depot5/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

and if i used any rails command like `rails db:create` the output is like this:

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE - /home/bassemustafa/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
/home/bassemustafa/rails/depot5/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/bassemustafa/rails/depot5/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/bassemustafa/rails/depot5/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/bassemustafa/rails/depot5/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/bassemustafa/rails/depot5/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/bassemustafa/rails/depot5/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**What's the problem?**

Comment: is the version in rbnv set right? From the logs, it's showing `2.4.2` but the ruby version is `2.4.0`.

Comment: how to change this? i only have 2.4.2 version installed and considered as global

Comment: You can set the ruby version in the Gemfile: `ruby "2.4.2"` typically as the last line of the file

Comment: @whodini9 it doesnt't help, The 2.4.0 mentioned in the error is a folder installed by rbenv automatically not a version in the Gemfile

Comment: I believe the problem is with your MySql version not ruby. Do you have MySQl installed?

Comment: @KwakuBoateng Yes i have mysql installed and mysql2 gem too, but i don't think the problem with the mysql because i can't even start the server

Comment: The server isn't starting because it can't load mysql. The end of the first line of your errors is: `.../mysql2.so (LoadError)` so you need to make sure that mysql is installed and running first. Show us what happens when you try to connect to mysql?

Comment: run `/etc/init.d/mysqld status` in the terminal to check if mysql is running. If indeed MySql is running then run `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart` in your terminal to restart MySql..

Comment: Thanks guys the problem was on my Mysql as you said